# Sort 3rd - 5th column not impacting column 1 or 2

Tags: excel, vba

I try to sort a specific range with different sort keys and use the following code:

```
Sub Sort()
    With Range("C1:E11").CurrentRegion
        .Sort Key1:=.Range("C1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Range("E1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
End Sub
```

When I run this code I want it to only sort Column C:E, but somehow columns A:B are added to the sort result. This is unexpected and not what I want.
What's wrong in the code?

Comment: Try removing the `currentregion`.

Comment: Then I get a runtime error '1004'.

Comment: the sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort By box isn't the same or blank.

Comment: Your keys are relative - `.range("e1")` is the fifth column of a 3 column range. Try recording a macro of the sort you want.

Comment: Thanks. If I want to sort column C in range C:E I get it done by referencing A1 (first column).

Comment: I don't really get the logic, but it works. I changed key1 to A1 and key to into C1 and it does what I wanted. Not to fond of the way it looks though.

Comment: Somehow I don't know how to accept your 2nd answer, since it led to solving my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it relative (not sure why), you could do this:

```
Sub Sort()
    With Range("C1:E11")
        .Sort Key1:=.Cells(1, 1), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Cells(1, 3), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
            OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    End With
End Sub
```